# Css variable in Email Template

Tags: css, html-email

I am making an email template and facing many issue in css. Is it a good idea to use css variable in email.

For example

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: pink;
 }

 td {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
 }
```

Is it going to break in some condition ? Should I avoid css variable in email template ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

It is better `not to use` css variables in email messages. Css variables are not supported in many web browsers.

[image: Summary]

For e-mail clients, it's even worse.

> what I know, only a few modern email clients can handle css variables.

Comment: For those looking for an up to date breakdown of what is supported in email clients you can find it here https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-variables/

Comment: 2024 and only Apple Mail properly supports it :(